# ext4 corruption leading to unbootable disk. Partition is mountable, but grub detects unknown filesystem

Tags: boot, ext4, grub, corruption, fsck

I'm trying to recover from a system disk corruption issue without having to reinstall the OS, which would be super-painful currently.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, the affected partition is ext4 and on a SSD disk.

Summary:

- Root partition gets remounted read-only after some error.
- `df -h` shows a huge partition (ZB) instead of the 800GB it should be.
- Boot with a live USB.
- Repair partition with `fsck -v`. Fixed some errors (orphaned inode and size is xxx should be 0).
- Mount the partition, looks fine. Can navigate, edit files, everything seems to be there and looking good.
- Reboot, the partition is now unbootable. I get the grub console, I can't `grub> ls` the partition; error is "error: unknown filesystem.". I get the same error from the live USB with "grub-mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt"
- I try to repair using [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#Getting_Boot-Repair%20). Unsuccessful, but now I have this [log with a report](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ntQHKyZHfV/).

Any ideas? To me the inconsistency between successfully mounting the partition with mount and unsuccessfully with grub-mount seems really strange. I guess if I could fix this I would be able to boot normally again.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: As an extra comment, every tool I tried (fdisk, gparted, ...) seem to detect a valid partition and do not report any issue. I have only issues mounting the partition with grub-mount (and of course, booting).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to copy your files, recreate the filesystem, format and then copy your files back. I don't think it worth trying to repair it.

Comment: Thank you. Would you recommend any tool in particular? dd, rsync or dump/restore? I have never backed up the whole root device (including dev, proc, sys, and so on...)

Comment: dd would transfer the bad parts as well so don't use dd. i would simply mount the volume in another linux machine and use cp